# PHP logging framework to be used with WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, testing, logging

There are different PHP logging frameworks out there e.g. Log4php, KLogger. I want to choose one based on its experience with WordPress. Please suggest me one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with KLogger more specifically a [**fork  of it**](https://github.com/stephens2424/KLogger) which is simple and clean, and i have a few sites logging using this simple class with no problems or complains.

Comment: Thanks! The fork you mentioned had some bugs in it. Are you using its latest version?

Comment: the fork mentioned has bug but no more then the original.